# Double Quote not working in Vim in command mode

Tags: vim

I want to copy text from vim buffer to the system clipboard by using the command "*y but when I press the double quote sign in command mode, it doesn't seem to get fired at all as I don't see anything in the status bar (nothing gets copied also even if I blindly continue with the command). I can see all other commands in the status bar in vim. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I have clipboard support enabled in my vim version.

Comment: Are you able to enter the double quote (e.g. in insert mode, other editors) "normally", or does it appear with a delay / only after another keypress?! Some keyboard layouts have special behavior.

Comment: you may also have been suffering from this https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6307/vim-doesnt-show-the-command-that-is-being-typed, I was!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should press `"+y` in NORMAL (or VISUAL) mode.

If you love to do it in command line, do this:

```
:y +
```

(same for `"*y`)

Comment: "+y worked fine for me but I'm able to copy only one line by :y+