# Vim on Mac OS X in Command Mode special keys not working

Tags: macos, vim

I have started the journey of learning Vim and after a few basics I wanted to use the system clipboard or/and record a macro.

However, when in Command Mode my <kbd>@</kbd> key is not working and neither is my at <kbd>"</kbd> key. It seems that my keyboard bindings are different in Command Mode, when in Insert Mode I can write **@** and **"** without a problem.

What is the issue here and how can I solve it?

The only related question I found did not solve my problem:([Double Quote not working in Vim in command mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896127/double-quote-not-working-in-vim-in-command-mode))

Comment: If you're running a *nix machine, can you type `echo $LANG` in the terminal and post the result? I'm thinking that it might be a language+keyboard issue...

Comment: I am using a German Mac with British keyboard settings, which meant renaming some keys but that is not the problem. `echo $LANG` gives `en_GB.UTF-8`.